# Range of immediate values in ARMv8 A64 assembly

Tags: assembly, arm64, gnu-assembler, immediate-operand

My understanding is that immediate parameters in ARMv8 A64 assembly can be 12 bits long.  If that is the case, why does this line of assembly code:

```
AND X12, X10, 0xFEF
```

Produce this error (when compiled with gcc)

```
Error:  immediate out of range at operand 3 -- `AND X12, X10, 0xFEF'
```

Interestingly enough, this line of assembly code compiles fine:

```
ADD X12, X10, 0xFEF
```

I'm using aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc (Linaro GCC 2014.11) 4.9.3 (prerelease)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unlike A32's "flexible second operand", there is no common immediate format in A64. For immediate-operand data-processing instructions (ignoring the boring and straightforward ones like shifts),

- Arithmetic instructions (`add{s}`, `sub{s}`, `cmp`, `cmn`) take a 12-bit unsigned immediate with an optional 12-bit left shift.
- Move instructions (`movz`, `movn`, `movk`) take a 16-bit immediate optionally shifted to any 16-bit-aligned position within the register.
- Address calculations (`adr`, `adrp`) take a 21-bit signed immediate, although there's no actual syntax to specify it directly - to do so you'd have to resort to assembler expression trickery to generate an appropriate "label".
- Logical instructions (`and{s}`, `orr`, `eor`, `tst`) take a "bitmask immediate", which I'm not sure I can even explain, so I'll just quote [the mind-bogglingly complicated definition](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0802b/AND_log_imm.html):

> Such an immediate is a 32-bit or 64-bit pattern viewed as a vector of identical elements of size e = 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits. Each element contains the same sub-pattern: a single run of 1 to e-1 non-zero bits, rotated by 0 to e-1 bits. This mechanism can generate 5,334 unique 64-bit patterns (as 2,667 pairs of pattern and their bitwise inverse).

Comment: This explanation makes a little more sense:  "The logical immediate instructions accept a bitmask immediate bimm32 or bimm64. Such an immediate consists EITHER of a single consecutive sequence with at least one non-zero bit, and at least one zero bit, within an
element of 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 or 64 bits; the element then being replicated across the register width, or the bitwise inverse of such a value. "

Comment: The arm bitmask immedate field is 13 bits (from what I can tell).  Does anybody know precisely how those bits are interpreted (i.e., the algorithm for converting these 13 bits into a 32 or 64-bit value)?  Why isn't that algorithm easy to find?

Comment: I found some code here that may be helpful:  http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/AArch64AddressingModes_8h_source.html

Comment: @Zack As with everything, the full, authoritative, definition can be found in the instruction pseudocode in [the ARM ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0487a.f/index.html) (free to download, but you have to sign up to accept the license). In this case it's the `DecodeBitMasks()` function in the pseudocode appendix (page J8-5588 in issue A.f).

Comment: Immediates for bitwise instructions aren't that hard to at least summarize: a repeating pattern, where within one element the set bits have to be contiguous.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a piece of code to dump all legal bitmask immediates following the mechanism quoted in [Notlikethat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30905104/). Hope it helps to understand how the rule for generating bitmask immediates work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// Dumps all legal bitmask immediates for ARM64
// Total number of unique 64-bit patterns: 
//   1*2 + 3*4 + 7*8 + 15*16 + 31*32 + 63*64 = 5334

const char *uint64_to_binary(uint64_t x) {
  static char b[65];
  unsigned i;
  for (i = 0; i < 64; i++, x <<= 1)
    b[i] = (0x8000000000000000ULL & x)? '1' : '0';
  b[64] = '\0';
  return b;
}

int main() {
  uint64_t result;
  unsigned size, length, rotation, e;
  for (size = 2; size <= 64; size *= 2)
    for (length = 1; length < size; ++length) {
      result = 0xffffffffffffffffULL >> (64 - length);
      for (e = size; e < 64; e *= 2)
        result |= result << e;
      for (rotation = 0; rotation < size; ++rotation) {
        printf("0x%016llx %s (size=%u, length=%u, rotation=%u)\n",
            (unsigned long long)result, uint64_to_binary(result),
            size, length, rotation);
        result = (result >> 63) | (result << 1);
      }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can run the output of this through sort to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative explanation of bitmask immediates, now that is is morning and I finally understood the "mind-boggingly complicated" definition. (See Notlikethat's answer.) Maybe it would be easier for some to understand.

It is X>0 consecutive zeros followed by Y>0 consecutive ones, where X+Y is a power of 2, repeated to fill the whole argument and then rotated arbitrarily.

Also note that optional shifts in other immediate formats are by **exact** amounts of bits, not "up to". That is, the 16-bit immediates can be shifted by 0, 16, 32 or 48 bits *exactly*, while 12-bit immediates *only* by 0 or 12 bits.

Comment: Interestingly, `and x13, x13, #0` and `#-1` aren't encodeable.  That's good, they didn't waste coding space on useless immediates: `0` as an operand for bitwise-booleans is either a NOP or a zeroing operation, and `eor x13, x13, x13` or `sub` can still produce a zero with a data-dependency on the input (`std::memory_order_consume`) in one instruction.  And that's so rarely needed it would have been fine to need two instructions for that.  `eor` with `-1` is just a NOT, which there's an instruction for.  `or` with `-1` would produce `-1` with a data dependency; can be done in 2 insns.

Comment: That makes sense: a 6-bit field can encode numbers from 0..63 or 1..64, but not 0..64.  And making one of the encodings special, you still have enough room to encode 1..63, with handles bit-ranges from one 1 (rest 0s) to one 0 (rest 1s).  I didn't check if that's how the machine code actually works.