# how do I dump the shellcode from an aarch64 binary with objcopy?

Tags: assembly, arm, elf, arm64, binutils

I have a simple assembly code (aarch64) as follows,

```
 mov x1, #1
 mov x1, #2
```

and I want to convert it to shellcode.

What I did:

```
#> as simple.s -o simple.o
#> objcopy -O binary simple.o simple.bin
```

after that, I checked the content of with xxd

```
#> xxd simple.bin
```

However, The value 1 and 2 are not seemed in result binary.

```
0000000: 2100 80d2 4100 80d2                      !...A...
```

did I use the objcopy wrongly ?

Comment: I also tried `strip simple.bin` before the objcopy. But the result was same.

Comment: BTW, you can't usefully `bl printf` from actual shellcode.  That assembles to a relative branch to a PLT stub in another section, which in turn loads a pointer from the GOT entry.  All of these things depend on absolute addresses set up by the dynamic linker, and/or their own address, and the randomized address of `printf` in libc.so, so aren't things that can be part of a self-contained position-independent block of machine code that could be injected anywhere.

Comment: But also, why bother to link your `simple` executable if you're going to objcopy from the `.o` object file?

Comment: More importantly, `as simple.s -o simple` doesn't write `simple.o`, so if that file exists it's probably from an old version of your source.

Comment: @PeterCordes you are right, using printf break the shellcode.

Comment: *However, The value 1 and 2 are not seemed in result binary.* - AArch64 encodes immediate in a complex way, not just using the low 8 or 12 bits of the instruction word literally. ([Range of immediate values in ARMv8 A64 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30904718))  Look at the machine code for those instructions in the `.o` (`objdump -d foo.o`) and see if it matches your hexdump.  Also, the xxd defaults for chunk size and endianness are not great for looking at AArch64 machine code!

Comment: Voting to close as not reproducible - the bytes you dumped are exactly the instructions you've written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARM instructions are 32-bit little-endian words, so will be easier to read if you dump them in this format.  Use `xxd -e simple.bin` which outputs:

```
00000000: d2800021 d2800041                    !...A...
```

This is the correct encoding for the `movz` instruction, see the ARMv8 Architecture Reference Manual.  The 16-bit immediate is encoded in bits 5-20, which is why the numbers 1 and 2 are not immediately obvious in the hexadecimal representation, but they are there.  (Bits 0-4 encode the destination register.)  They would be easier to see in binary, but xxd doesn't seem to have a 32-bit little-endian binary mode.

So your output file is perfectly correct.