# How do I copy an address from one register into another?

Tags: arm

I'm working in an arm-like architecture which is vastly simplified for students called LEGv8. A problem asked "return the address in register X7" and the address is currently in X0. The solution that was provided said "ADDI X7,X0,#0." Would MOV also work to copy the address from one register to another, or is MOV specifically for data values and why does ADD work? Also LDUR I'm just trying to understand all of the subtleties in nomenclature and how they all connect. Also when people say store one value from one register into another, are they referring the address or? Thanks in advance!

I mistakenly tried using LDUR, but I'm not looking for solutions because I already have a solution, I'm looking for a better understanding of how registers and memory all work.

Comment: `MOV` would certainly do the job on an actual ARM CPU - but this LEGv8 variant doesn't actually *have* a `MOV` instruction (it's listed as a pseudo instruction, which probably expands to the `ADDI reg,reg,#0` you already know about).  Note that `EORI reg,reg,#0` or `ORRI reg,reg,#0` would also work, these are all simply operations that don't affect the register value being stored.

Comment: @jasonharper: LEGv8 is a simplification of ARM64 which doesn't actually have a `MOV Xd, Xm` instruction either: it's an alias of `ORR Xd, XZR, Xm`.  Your suggestion of `ADD Xd, Xm, #0` would also suffice, and is actually used by ARM64 assemblers for `MOV` to and from the stack pointer `SP` which isn't usable as an operand for `ORR`.  However `ORR Xd, Xm, #0` and `EOR Xd, Xm, #0` are not encodable in real ARM64, because the immediate operand for bitwise logic instructions is a [bitmask immediate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30904718/634919) which cannot encode the value 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you read [the LEGv8 instruction set](https://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/lmcdowel/courses/ic220/S20/resources/ARM-v8-Quick-Reference-Guide.pdf) carefully, there is actually no such instruction as `MOV` at all.  There is `MOVZ` and `MOVK`, both of which are only to move an immediate value into a register.

`MOV` is listed only as a pseudo-instruction, i.e. an alias for another instruction (or in the case of `LDA`, possibly for multiple instructions).  The card doesn't say what it's an alias for.  However, on real ARMv8 assemblers, `MOV Xd, Xm` is an alias for `ORR Xd, XZR, Xm`, so that would in some sense be the "canonical" solution, and therefore the one likely to be best optimized by real-life ARMv8 CPUs.  Your suggestion of `ADDI Xd, Xm, #0` would work too, but may not be as optimal.

Hopefully the reason why `ADDI` works is obvious: adding 0 to a number doesn't change it, so the result written to `Xd` is equal to the value originally in `Xm`.  Logical OR with 0 doesn't change a number either, which is why `ORR` with the zero register works too.

`LDUR` is not what you want here, since it actually loads a value from data memory.  In your case, the values you need are already in registers, and you don't want to access memory at all.

Speaking of "storing a value from one register into another" is sloppy wording, because in the context of the ARM architecture, the word "store" is consistently used to mean a store into memory, never into a register.  Anyone who says that probably means a *move* from one register into another, not accessing memory.

Possibly the use of the word "address" in "return the *address* in register X7" is confusing you.  Any equivalent form of `MOV X0, X7`, would move the *value* from X7, i.e. whatever bits happen to be there, into X0, which is where return values are passed.  Presumably in the larger context of the problem, those bits happen to represent the address of some object in memory.  But that distinction only exists in the mind of the programmer; the CPU is just moving bits.