# In ARM machine code, how is the offset encoded in SUB SP, SP, #36?

Tags: assembly, arm, machine-code, immediate-operand

**Edit:**
**My concern is how ARM instruction is encoded.**

Let's examine below example:

```
  194640:   e92d40f0    push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
  194644:   e24dd024    sub sp, sp, #36 ; 0x24
  --> sp decrease 36 ~ 0x24 --> Is it calculated by e24dd024 & 0x0000ffff ?

  1995ec:   e92d4ef0    push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, r9, sl, fp, lr}
  1995f0:   e24ddd0a    sub sp, sp, #640    ; 0x280
  1995f4:   e1a04000    mov r4, r0
  --> sp decrease 640 ~ 0x280 --> How it is calculated ?

 Other examples:
  191ea8:   e92d4030    push    {r4, r5, lr}
  191eac:   e24dd034    sub sp, sp, #52 ; 0x34
  191eb0:   e28d5014    add r5, sp, #20

  194f54:   e28d60a8    add r6, sp, #168    ; 0xa8
  194f58:   e28d5e13    add r5, sp, #304    ; 0x130
```

Comment: AArch64 doesn't use simple 16-bit immediates like MIPS.  Check the manual for how instructions like ADD/SUB encode large immediates.  (It's different from bitwise boolean instructions like AND.)  BTW, I fixed your question title; you can't of course calculate SP, that would be like asking "what's x after x -= 36"

Comment: yes, encode large immediates is the keyword. Now it is clear to me :)

Comment: I think AArch64 add/sub uses a shifted or rotated value, probably 8 bits (correction, 12 bits).  `0xa << 6 = 0x280` would explain why there's a `0a` at the bottom of the machine code, but I'd have to look up the rules for how the shift or rotate count is encoded; feel free to post an answer to your own question if you found the docs, unless there's a duplicate already on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The explanation in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763582/how-to-encode-immediate-value-in-arm is clear for me. For e24ddd0a, 0x0A (1010 in binary) should be rotated right by (2*D=2*13=26), it means the last bit 0 of 0x0A is on the bit 25 (staring from 0, bit 25 is counted as 26), so the final result is 1010 00 0000 ~ 0x280

Comment: Oh wait a minute, this is 32-bit ARM, not the [arm64] you originally tagged.  I didn't notice before, but the reg names are `r0` not `w0` or `x0`.  And of course the multi-register push. No wonder the earlier duplicate link I found didn't seem right to match well with the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

```
  push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
  sub     sp, sp, #36 ; 0x24
```

That's basically a function 'prologue'. 
Function preserves registers it's gonna to change (`push` instruction) and reserve stack (`sub sp,...`) for function internal variables and intermediate preservation of registers.

So to put it simple, the more variables function uses, the bigger is number subtracted from `sp`. Note, that's also depends on `sizeof(x)` of variables. Say if function declares a some big structure, that would take more stack to accommodate it.
Exact value is defined by compiler, and could vary depending on compilation settings.

Comment: I *think* the question is about trying to understand the machine code, like where the `0x280` comes from in `e24ddd0a`  (disassembly: `sub sp, sp, #0x280`).

Comment: hmm... that did not make such an impression on me. Question should be better formulated then. Something with words 'instruction encoding' probably

Comment: I already re-titled it before you answered (for that reason), but didn't rewrite the question body.  Mostly irrelevant now since I found a duplicate.  On my first reading, I thought the OP was trying to calculate the *value* of SP itself, from an instruction that just modified it.